# How to customize both, width of the bar & spacing between bar in Highcharts.js

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I want to make something like this

[image]

here goes my sample code :-

```
           plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    pointWidth: 80,
                    groupPadding: 4,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.y:.1f}%',
                    }
                }
            },
```

i am confused between pointWidh & groupPadding property, only one property woks at a time.
when give only pointWidth, width applies, and when groupPadding only, it also applies. but i want these property doesn't apply at the same time.
what am i doing wrong
here's the reproduce example
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-pointpadding-025/

Comment: are you using official npm package for react for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official ?

Comment: yup @SirajAlam, i am using official react npm package

Answer (score 1):

I have written the complete working code, let me know if something is unclear.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderRadius: 8,
            pointWidth: 50
        }
    },

    series: [{
    data: [{y: 29.9, color: '#ff7841'}, {y: 71.5, color: '#ffa03c'}, {y: 106.4, color: '#ffbb39'}, {y: 129.2, color: '#b0bf05'}, {y:144.0, color: '#00bcb9'}, {y: 176.0, color: '#05a7cd'}, {y: 135.6, color: '#4d7ed7'}]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

---

This fiddle seems very close to your design.

https://jsfiddle.net/sirajalam049/zxw0nLpr/7/

[image]

Comment: but how will increase spacing between the bars as well as i want to give a poinWidth of 80

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you check, can you specify the exact with and spacing?